Point to mydomain but still allow email
Problem: I want my apps to point to mydomain.co.uk but still allow email to work through another provider.
Background: ISP is BT, which also manages email. BT provides a dynamic public IP address, but I don’t want to change. However, my domain name registrar also includes unlimited email forwarders. As an example, an eMail to anything@mydomain.co.uk is forwarded to myname@mydomain.co.uk which is then forwarded to myname@btinternet.com. I have tried Dynu. This was successful except for email. I had to use Dynu name servers on my domain management account and all email stopped.

Practically speaking, email uses a different type of DNS record to your web and apps.  In order to have your apps point to one place but your email to another you need to -

Ensure you have at least 1 MX records (Mail eXchange) record set up and pointing to your mail provider.   Note that this will direct email to your provider and is the minimum required, however to make mail work well (with respect of spam) you want to have other records like SPF, DKIM and DMARC.  You would need to get this information from your mail provider - or look at the old DNS zone file if you still have it.   You might struggle to fit this into 4 records provided on the Dynu free account but it should work on their paid account (according to their website - I've never used it)

You need to ensure that mydomain.co.uk does not use a CNAME record.  It can use an A record pointing to an IP address, but a CNAME record does not work as one would intuitively think and will block email.    (You can have www.mydomain.co.uk as a CNAME here though)


